# Error: toString() unavailable - no suspended threads

Tags: android, sockets

Am streaming data using socket and my program is

```
 class MyClass()
    {
    String ipadd;
    int port;

    MyClass(String s, int p)
    {
    this.ipadd = "10.0.2.2";
    this.port = 8080;
    }

    Socket s = new Socket (ipadd, port);
         ..........
    }
```

But am getting an error of 1) `s= null, toString() unavailable - no suspended threads` .
2)`Connection exception: failed to connect 10.0.2.2: connection failed.`
Here am testing it on my emulator and i gave permissions in my manifest file.My only question is why am getting the error of `toString() unavailable - no suspended threads` why it is caused and how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
 class socket()
{
String ipadd;
String port;

socket(String s, int p)
{
this.ipadd = "10.0.2.2";
this.port = "8080";
}

Socket s = new Socket (ipadd, port);
     ..........
}
```

"8080" This needs to be in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error. The problem was with my ip address. Once i gave the server ip address error vanished. Reason is while we are sending the request some firewall may block or some thing should listen to your connection.